# Problem painting JLabel class to another JPanel class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, jlabel

I have created a class that extends JLabel to use as my object moving around a JPanel for a game.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Head extends JLabel {

 int xpos;
 int ypos;

 int xvel;
 int yvel;

 ImageIcon chickie = new ImageIcon(
        "C:\\Users\\jjpotter.MSDOM1\\Pictures\\clavalle.jpg");
 JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(chickie);

 public Head(int xpos, int ypos, int xvel, int yvel){

  this.xpos = xpos;
  this.ypos = ypos;
  this.xvel = xvel;
  this.yvel = yvel;
 }

 public void draw(){
  myLabel.setLocation(xpos, ypos);
 }

 public double getXpos() {
  return xpos;
 }

 public double getYpos() {
  return ypos;
 }

 public int getXvel() {
  return xvel;
 }

 public int getYvel() {
  return yvel;
 }

 public void setPos(int x, int y){

  xpos = x;
  ypos = y;

 }

}
```

I am then trying to add it onto my JPanel. From here I will randomly have it increment its x and y coordinates to float it around the screen. I can not get it to paint itself onto the JPanel. I know there is a key concept I am missing here that involves painting components on different panels. Here is what I have in my GamePanel class

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

 Random myRand = new Random();
 Head head = new Head(20,20,0,0);

 public GamePanel(){

  this.setSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
  this.add(head);

 }

}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to add to the JPanel? Also, is this a good way to go about having the picture float around the screen randomly for a game?

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no need to extend a JLabel to do this.

a) you set the size of the label after you add the image to the label by using:

```
label.setSize( label.getPreferredSize() );
```

b) You don't need the draw(), and all the setter methods. To move the label all you do is use:

```
label.setLocation(...);
```

c) if you want to increment the location you would use something like:

label.setLocation( label.getLocation().x + 5, ...);

Once you set the size and location of the label you can add it directly to the panel. Make sure you have done:

```
panel.setPreferredSize()
```

when you add your panel to the content pane of your frame.

Your code is too vague to give specific suggestions. If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Your problem could be the usage of layout manager or the fact you aren't using layout managers.

Comment: This does make it a lot easier. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should set the layout manager for your JPanel ( GamePanel ) to null that tells the system:

*Don't place it for me, I'll do it manually*

**edit**

I think it would be clearer if I give you a running demo.

See this example. As camickr points, you don't have to subclass the components.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.*;

class FloatingDemo {
    public static void main( String [] args ){
        // create the panel         
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        // create the label with an image
        final JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("StackOverflowLogo.png"));
        label.setSize(label.getIcon().getIconWidth(), 
                      label.getIcon().getIconHeight());
        panel.add( label );

        // create the frame containing both 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setSize(800, 600 );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        // move it randomly every second  
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        final Random random = new Random();
        timer.schedule( new TimerTask() {
           public void run(){
                 label.setLocation( random.nextInt(800-label.getWidth()), 
                                    random.nextInt(600-label.getHeight()));       
           } 
        }, 0, 1000 );

    }
}
```

BTW, not setting the layout manager to null also works, but if you resize the window, the jpanel would automatically set the location for you.

[running demo http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/2567/capturadepantalla201006c.png](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/2567/capturadepantalla201006c.png)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I believe is that you don't really add the image to `Head` in your constructor.

What you need to do is create a new `ImageIcon` like you are doing, and in your constructor do something lie this;

```
public Head(int xpos, int ypos, int xvel, int yvel){
    // calls the JLabel constructor to create a label with an image
    super(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jjpotter.MSDOM1\\Pictures\\clavalle.jpg"))
    this.xpos = xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
    this.xvel = xvel;
    this.yvel = yvel;
}
```

This will create your `Head` with the specified image.

Once you sort out the constructor issue, you can then call setLocation() on you `Head` object from the `JPanel` you have added it to.  That is how you can move it around randomly.

Also, in the `JPanel` you are adding the `Head` to, you need to make sure you set the `LayoutManaer` to null, so you can manually place the component on the panel yourself.